# elasticsearch filter aggs by doc count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that counts the number of images per user:

```
GET images/_search
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
      {
        "term": {
           "appID.raw": "myApp"
      }
    }
  ]
 }
},
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "perDeviceAggregation": {
    "terms": {
       "field": "deviceID"    
    }
  }
 }
}
```

It basically works fine, but I would like to exclude all aggregation results for users that have less than 200 images. How can I tweak the query above to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: could you post your mapping and couple of sample documents? in which field image is stored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a [Minimum Document Count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) option.

```
"aggs": {
      "perDeviceAggregation": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "deviceID",
            "min_doc_count": 200
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a filter aggregation to your terms aggregation with the query clause.
[Filter Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html)

You can modify your above query to look like this.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "appID.raw": "myApp"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_users_with_images_count": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "count": 200
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "perDeviceAggregation": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "deviceID"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify the filter inside filtered_users_with_images_count to match documents with images greater than 200.

Please also consider to post your data mappings along with query to support your questions.